What means dual dating at cover page of Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica?
On cover page of Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica write two years,
Julii 5, 1686 and "Anno MDCLXXXVII(1687)".
What these two years represent?


The First date is  in a statement:

IMRIMATUR S. PEPYS, Reg. Soc. PRAESES, Julii 5 1686

Which seems to be at least partially in Latin.
Imprimatur is an English word clearly based on Latin which means:
1 a : SANCTION, APPROVAL
b : IMPRINT

c : a mark of approval or distinction

2 a : a license to print or publish especially by Roman Catholic episcopal authority
b  : approval of a publication under circumstances of official censorship

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imprimatur
I note that the famous Samuel Pepys was the President of the Royal Society of London from 1 December 1684 to 30 November 1686.
And the Latin word Praeses means "chairman" or "president".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praeses
And "Royal Society" in Latin is Regia Societas, which is abbreviated  Reg. Soc..
So that statement is that Samuel Pepys, President of the Royal Society, gave his imprimatur or sanction or approval to the book on July 5, 1686.
And so the other date, MDCLXXXVII, or 1687 in Roman numerals, must be the publication year.

Book was published  July 5, 1687 by Julian calendar?
